# Stochastic transparency for rendering transparent clouds

Tags: opengl, blending, draw-order

I'm experimenting with stochastic transparency in openGL to avoid sorting my scene which consists of clouds at different positions. I'm trying to implement the method described here https://blog.bonzaisoftware.com/stochastic-order-independent-transparency/. In my accumulation shader I experimented with different things and here is what I'm using now:

```
FragColor = currentPixel + accumulatedPixel) / numSamples;
FragColor = clamp(FragColor, 0.0, 1.0);
```

and my rendering loop is like this:

```
int numSamplesPerPixel = 25; // Adjust as needed
ourShader.setInt("numSamples", numSamplesPerPixel);
for (int i = 0; i < numSamplesPerPixel; ++i) {
        // Bind the appropriate framebuffer
        float time = static_cast<float>(glfwGetTime());
        GLuint currentFramebuffer = (i % 2 == 0) ? framebuffer1 : framebuffer2;
        GLuint otherFramebuffer = (i % 2 == 0) ? framebuffer2 : framebuffer1;
        GLuint currentFramebufferTexture = (i % 2 == 0) ? texture1 : texture2;
        GLuint accumulationTexture = (i % 2 == 0) ? texture2 : texture1;
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, currentFramebuffer);
        ourShader.use();
        ourShader.setFloat("time",time);
        
        glDrawElementsInstanced(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0, cloud_cluster.numClouds);

        // Accumulate the rendered image onto the accumulation framebuffer
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, otherFramebuffer);
        accumulateShader.use();
        accumulateShader.setInt("currentFrame",0);
        accumulateShader.setInt("accumulationBuffer", 1);
        accumulateShader.setInt("numSamples", numSamplesPerPixel);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, currentFramebufferTexture); // Use the texture associated with currentFramebuffer
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, accumulationTexture); // Use the texture associated with otherFramebuffer
        // Render a quad covering the entire screen, blending the current framebuffer with the accumulation buffer
        glBindVertexArray(quadVAO);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, quadVBO);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
    }
```

Here is what I'm getting now, it is very clear that there is some black dots inside the clouds. How can I fix that? Am I using stochastic transparency correctly?
[image: The appearance of clouds]

EDIT:

the original shader looks like this:

```
FragColor = texture(textureArray, vec3(TexCoord,int(imageIndexOut)));
float rand = random(vec3(gl_FragCoord.xy, time));
if (FragColor.a < rand){
    discard;
}
```

where random is a function I use descirbed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200224/random-noise-functions-for-glsl in the second answer. Time is passed at each iteration and now I see that the cloud pixels are changing constantly.

Comment: How are you varying your noise between samples? Is it possible some samples are consistently hitting coherent noise values, and not getting the amount of randomization/decorrelation you need?

Comment: Your accumulation function looks a bit odd too. It looks like the current RGB has been pre-scaled to 1/sampleCount, while for the alpha it's the accumulated value that's been scaled, and not by the reciprocal? Can you explain your thinking here?

Comment: We need the source code of the shaders to workout why the noise has such high contrast (unusable quality). DMGregory's first comment is most likely cause.

Comment: @DMGregory thanks for your replies. I edited the post above and fixed passing the time unifrom in the render loop. Now when the time is passed correctly, I get a new problem and it's that the cloud pixels constantly change, some becoming black and then change to white and vice versa. Do you think it is enough with the time and FragCoord.xy to avoid patterns in the noise values? The code of the fragment shaders of accumulationShader and "ourShader" is basically what I wrote plus the noise function. Do you think my approach at creating stochastic transparency this way works?

Comment: @Blindman67 I commented above and edited the post

Comment: Also the accumulation function looked odd but now I just add all the RGBA channels and divide by numSamples